# Query in VB2010 based on indian language

Tags: sql, .net

I am developing a application based on native Indian language. I have to search the database column (in native language) student name in native language. Can anybody help me to solve this issue

my query builder code looks like this and shows syntax error

```
SELECT        [ಕ್ರಮ ಸಂಖ್ಯೆ], [ವಿದ್ಯಾರ್ಥಿಯ ಹೆಸರು] AS Name, [ರಜಿಸ್ಟರ್ ಸಂಖ್ಯೆ], [ಡೈಸ್ ಸಂಖ್ಯೆ], [ವರ್ಗ], [ಕನ್ನಡ], [ಇಂಗ್ಲೀಷ], [ಹಿಂದಿ], [ಗಣಿತ], [ವಿಜ್ಞಾನ], [ಸಮಾಜ ವಿಜ್ಞಾನ], [ದೈಹಿಕ ಶಿಕ್ಷಣ], [ಒಟ್ಟು ಅಂಕಗಳು], [ಶೇಕಡಾ], [ಶ್ರೇಣಿ], [ಒಟ್ಟು ಅಂಕಗಳು ಅಕ್ಷರದಲ್ಲಿ], [ಲ,ಕ/ಕಲಾ ಶಿಕ್ಷಣ], [ಕಂಪ್ಯೂಟರ ಶಿಕ್ಷಣ], [ಫಲಿತಾಂಶ]
FROM            Table11
WHERE         ವಿದ್ಯಾರ್ಥಿಯ ಹೆಸರುCollate Indic_General_100_CI_AI  LIKE N '%ಮ%'
```

Comment: The WHERE doesn't seem to contain a condition

Comment: try to include column in WHERE clause in square brackets `WHERE [ವಿದ್ಯಾರ್ಥಿಯ ಹೆಸರು] Collate Indic_General_100_CI_AI LIKE N '%ಮ%'`

Answer (score 0):

I notice a couple things right off.  Because the field in your where clause has a space in it... you have to put delimiters around it.  Also, you don't seem to have a space between your field and the Collate keyword... that is necessary.  Lastly, you can not have a space between the N and the apostrophe to specify a nvarchar string literal.  So try a where clause like this:

```
WHERE [ವಿದ್ಯಾರ್ಥಿಯ ಹೆಸರು] Collate Indic_General_100_CI_AI LIKE N'%ಮ%'
```

If you are still getting an error, it could be that your field `[ವಿದ್ಯಾರ್ಥಿಯ ಹೆಸರು]` is not of a unicode string type.  Make sure the field is defined as nvarchar, nchar,...etc.

From your comment it appears that you are querying a MS Access database.  The above is for querying a SQL Server Engine.  The where clause for access would look like this:

```
WHERE [ವಿದ್ಯಾರ್ಥಿಯ ಹೆಸರು] LIKE '*ಮ*'
```

Comment: Thanks Brain for the comments I rectified the code as you suggested but still I am getting an error as follows  Error in WHERE clause near 'ವಿದ್ಯಾರ್ಥಿಯ ಹೆಸರು'.
Unable to parse query text.   Since I have created a table in access and imported it I dont know how to specify it as Unicode while importing it. Can you suggest any solution where in I convert the word to nchar before passing it to query builder

Comment: Your query looks like it's written for MS SQL Server... are you sending it to a Jet Database Engine with data stored in MS Access?